# get Param return undefined

Tags: aura, parameters

my code is :

```
    ({submit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var msg = component.get('v.inputValue');
        var mainMsg ="Hey this is "+ msg + "." ; 
 
        var myEvent = $A.get('e.c:MyFirstAuraEvent');
        myEvent.setParams({
            msg: mainMsg
                })      
        myEvent.fire();
        
        console.log(myEvent.getParam("msg"));       
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myEvent.setParams({
msg: mainMsg
})
myEvent.fire();

change this code :
myEvent.setParams({
message: mainMsg                       //message is predefined attribute
})
myEvent.fire();